# how to set GDI HDC's drawable region?

Tags: gdi, stretchdibits

I want to draw a HBITMAP onto HDC,

I used StretchDIBits. It works fine.
::StretchDIBits.

however, I only want a window to watch the drawing result, beside the window, I wish the stretchDIBits do not take any effect(It can not draw on other area), how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a child window is created, make sure the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style is set to disallow painting outside the client area in `WM_PAINT`.

Other than that, `SelectClipRegion` is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks,  I used SelectClipRgn, It works! Another question, how to cancel SelectClipRgn's effect after drawing? then, other process can work on the total hdc

Comment: Cancel by calling with a NULL region. If you liked the answer, then, maybe, you could upvote me a bit...  ;-)